# Substitute both the beginning and end of every occurrence of a string with vim

Tags: vim

I have more than a hundred of occurrences of the string `?dep=` followed by two numbers. So it goes like `?dep=01`, `?dep=02`, `?dep=03`, etc.
I need to change the string but keep the numbers at the same time, so for example

```
?dep=01
```

needs to become

```
{{ path('annonce-index', {departement: 01}) }}
```

How can I do that with the substitute command in vim?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can be done with a simple *capture group*: match both the part that gets removed (`?dep=`) and the part that will be kept (`\d\d`), but enclose the latter in `\(...\)` to *capture* it. Then, in the replacement, refer to the *first* capture via `\1`:

```
:%s/?dep=\(\d\d\)/{{ path('annonce-index', {departement: \1}) }}/g
```

The `:%` applies this to the *entire* buffer, the `/g` flag applies this to multiple matches in a single line. Read `:help /\(` and `:help :substitute` for more information.

Comment: Glad I could help. Please don't forget to accept the answer by clicking on the outlined check mark next to it.